# Migrate SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle

I need to migrate data (including tables, procedures, schema) from Sql Server 2005 to Oracle 10g. Can anyone suggest me a way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Oracle Migration Workbench](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[SwisSQL](http://www.swissql.com/) have a commercial tool that will do that. It can go from and to several different database vendors. I've used it before to go from SQL Server to Oracle and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work around is by using ORACLE GATEWAY First create tables, views, stored procedures and triggers in *ORACLE* and then using ORACLE GATEWAY you can directly insert the data from *SQLSERVER* to *ORACLE*.

But you need to be cautious about data types. For migrating data from *Image*, *TEXT* you need to use *DBMS_Sql*

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible options is to use SQL Developer. It is an Oracle free tool, which migrates both database objects and data. However, you need to have high level of knowledge in database migration, in particular experience of working with Oracle and SQL Server. Sometimes the results of automatic migration with SQL Developer require significant manual adjustments.